Halochos of Marital Relations
In Peninei Halakha - Simḥat Ha-bayit U-virkhato 02:12, Rabbi Melamed makes it quite clear that he considers the wife's orgasm as a critical part of the mitzva of Ona, and that even if the wife is uninterested in attaining that then every effort should be taken to remedy that situation.  Is this normative halacha or do other opinions disagree with this?  I know that some Rabbonim, even those who generally like Peninei Halacha are not always entirely happy with everything in this specific Sefer, but I have never asked details about this specifically as it is a very sensitive subject.

This context is no less sensitive

I thought Jewish families start because from the moment of marriage they obligate themselves to be interested. While the subject is sensitive - failure to recognize this point perhaps shows that marriage was not created with a right attitude and probably for some exterior reasons.

@RabbiKaii Apologies - I had seen a number of other questions on this sort of topic that hadn't been closed and had assumed that this was an allowed topic.  I wouldn't be asking without very good reason.

+1 Jewish tradition assumes that the woman enjoys the act by default without any additional help. Because the a Mitzvah of Onah - systematic intimacy - is considered the husband's obligation toward the wife, her satisfaction is implied. Only in modern times, women's physiology was researched and several conclusions were drawn. Now, it is a matter of the values hierarchy - some rabbis value Shlom Bays and support sex-ed, and some prefer adherence and religious zeal and sticking to the tradition. It is worth mentioning that the latter type would agree with the former in private meetings.

@YDJ There can be other reasons.  In this case I suspect sensory issues and autistic traits are part of it.  In any case, would you say that a woman who has naturally very low levels of desire but wants to do the מצוה of פרו ורבו has the wrong attitude?  She might even be totally unaware that her lack of interest is unusual.

@AlBerko Thanks, but that doesn't deal with a case where she considers herself to be satisfied with a more minimal interaction.

@Kvetch in such a case it is a question to specialists and family for assistance.

The Talmud says that it's just a matter of the husband restraining himself long enough:

Is it within the power of men to increase the number of their sons...?
[Yes.]  If they restrain themselves during intercourse to allow their wives to have an orgasm first, their children shall be males, and they will acquire great merit.
Rabbi Kattina said: “I could make all my children to be males.”
Rava said: “One who wishes all his children to be males should have intercourse twice in succession.” [Because the second time he is better able to restrain himself.] [Niddah 31a-b]


+1 for effort. What translation do you use? I understand that in the modern world, תזריע is associated with women's orgasm, but it is not so clear, since the Gemmorah provides absolutely no tips and tricks on inducing or facilitating it. As you can see later on the same page "And Rabbi Yitzḥak says...: A woman becomes pregnant only by engaging in intercourse close to the onset of her menstrual cycle" their understanding of physiology was pretty limited, and no rabbis claim to perfect a method of inducting their wives' הזרעה.
